# MySQL Update not setting new flag

Tags: mysql

i don't know why but the update isn't working, any idea ?
in normal case it should check if the code input is valid (code) after that it should set row "used" to 1 for the code var $name

```
<?php
 $hostname = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$usertable = "codes";
$yourfield = "code";
$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
connect to database! Please try again later.");
mysql_select_db($dbname);



$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE $yourfield = '" . $_GET["code"] . "' AND used = 0";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rowSelected   = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($rowSelected ) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $row["$yourfield"];
        $wert = $row["wert"];
        echo "Code valid<br>";
        echo "Code: $name<br>";
        echo "Value: $wert";
        $mysql_query($connection, 'UPDATE codes SET used=1 WHERE code="$name"');

    }


}
else {
echo "Code invalid!";
}
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are wrong in

```
'UPDATE codes SET used=1 WHERE code="$name"'
```

They should be

```
"UPDATE codes SET used=1 WHERE code='$name'"
```

Comment: ok changed but doesn't fixed the problem, no update change on row used